# Python Visualising a Dict with a List of values

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dict with several keys, and its values is a list. I want to visualise per key the list.

Example of dict of key: 
Key: 4193
Value: [u'9039', u'7783', u'6328']

Key: 3522
Value: [u'9039', u'6425', u'5377']

My outcome should be something like below in a graph.

### 4193

9039
7783
6328

### 3522

9039
6425
5377

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.iteritems()` function to loop through the key and values.

For example:

```
In [7]: d = {"4193": [u'9039', u'7783', u'6328'], "3522": [u'9039', u'6425', u'5377']}
In [8]: for key, value in d.iteritems():
...:     print key
...:     print " ".join(value)
...:     

3522
9039 6425 5377
4193
9039 7783 6328

In [9]:
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to visualise this a seperate graph with the key on top and the rest of the values below?

Comment: @JeroenWefersBettink What do you mean by a separate graph??

Comment: I would like to export it to a figure, to use in presentation or report.

Comment: @JeroenWefersBettink You can loop through the key, values of the dictionary and can use it where ever you want.